# How to read K-Fold Cross Validation results?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

If I have two models to be validated, how I could figure which model is the best? Is it the one who has bigger score, or the smaller one? Any reference for in-depth explanation and example for k-fold cross validation? Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends on what score you're computing using cross-validation.

Comment: @MarcClaesen, I think it used concordance-index measurement

Comment: Then higher is better.